# Counting the number of 10-digit numbers in a file

Tags: bash, grep

I need to count the total number of instances in which a 10-digit number appears within a file. All of the numbers have leading zeros, e.g.:

```
This is some text. 0000000001
```

Returns:

```
1
```

If the same number appears more than once, it is counted again, e.g.:

```
0000000001 This is some text.
0000000010 This is some more text.
0000000001 This is some other text.
```

Returns:

```
3
```

Sometimes there are no spaces between the numbers, but each continuous string of 10-digits should be counted:

```
00000000010000000010000000000100000000010000000001
```

Returns:

```
5
```

How can I determine the total number of 10-digit numbers appearing in a file?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this:

```
grep -o '[0-9]\{10\}' inputfilename | wc -l
```

Comment: Cool, didn't know about `-o`.

Answer (score 2):

The last requirement - that you need to count multiple numbers per line - excludes grep, as far as I know it can count only per-line.

**Edit:** Obviously, I stand corrected by Nate :) grep's `-o` option is what I was looking for.

You can however do this easily with `sed` like this:

```
$ cat mkt.sh 
sed -r -e 's/[^0-9]/./g' -e 's/[0-9]{10}/num /g' -e 's/[0-9.]//g' $1
$ for i in *.txt; do echo --- $i; cat $i; echo --- number count; ./mkt.sh $i|wc -w; done
--- 1.txt
This is some text. 0000000001

--- number count
1
--- 2.txt
0000000001 This is some text.
0000000010 This is some more text.
0000000001 This is some other text.

--- number count
3
--- 3.txt
00000000010000000010000000000100000000010000000001

--- number count
5
--- 4.txt
1 2 3 4 5 6 6 7 9 0
11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 99 00
123456789 0

--- number count
0
--- 5.txt
1.2.3.4.123
1234567890.123-AbceCMA-5553///q/\1231231230
--- number count
2
$
```

Comment: What if all the numbers are not 10 digits long?

Comment: @potong then they would not meet the spec

Comment: But they might with this solution e.g. `'1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0'` returns `'1 '`

Comment: @potong Ah, good catch, thanks! Edited, should work properly now. Obviously, Nate's solution is much preferred :)

Answer (score 1):

`"I need to count the total number of instances in which a 10-digit number appears within a file. All of the numbers have leading zeros"`

So I think this might be more accurate:

```
$ grep -o '0[0-9]\{9\}' filename | wc -l
```

Comment: Why `\{9\}`? This doesn't seem to add anything over the answers already given.

Comment: Because of `All of the numbers have leading zeros` so i separate the first '0' digit, and then left 9 digits :)

Comment: With this logic `0,,,,,,,,,` would be a 10-digit number whereas `0123456789` would not.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
cat <<! >test.txt
0000000001 This is some text.
0000000010 This is some more text.
0000000001 This is some other text.
00000000010000000010000000000100000000010000000001
1 a 2 b 3 c 4 d 5 e 6 f 7 g 8 h 9 i 0 j
12345 67890 12 34 56 78 90
!
sed 'y/X/ /;s/[0-9]\{10\}/\nX\n/g' test.txt | sed '/X/!d' | sed '$=;d'
8
```